# How can I 'ignore' images when reading in a document with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

When I read a document with Apache POI, even if I do nothing with images they are still read in.

Is there a way to 'skip over' the image reading part of the code? We have a lot of documents to read, which all have images we don't want, and it's massively slowing down the whole process.